# How do i stop text showing up when user types during execution of bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

You can see what problem I'm having just by doing `sleep 10` and typing.

How would I go about stopping that typing from showing?

Comment: You could turn off echo using `stty -echo`, and turn it back on when you want to see keys being pressed with `stty echo` … but it's dangerous if the user ^C's the script during execution. However if you're trying to read a password, bash's built-in `read -s` should do the trick

Comment: @Petesh Worked great! Thank you!

Comment: `stty -echo` doesn't stop the typing; it just prevents the text from appearing on-screen. Anything the user types is still next in line for anything that reads from standard input.

Answer (score 3):

To turn off keyboard echo, you can use `stty -echo`. To turn it back on you can do `stty echo`. To be safe, you would save the stty state and restore it at the end; however if you're reading a password, bash has a built-in `-s` option to read.

In summary:

```
stty -echo
# keyboard input is not echoed
stty echo
# keyboard input is echoed
```

More complete:

```
state=$(stty -g)
stty -echo
# keyboard is not echoed
stty "$state"
# state is restored.
```

Better, if you're just asking for a password, and using bash:

```
read -s password
# password is now in the variable $password; no stty shenanigans
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this like that:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exit_trap ()
{
  # Purge pending typed data if any
  # While there is data to read
  while read -rt0
  do IFS= read -r # read the data
  done < /dev/tty # from the tty terminal
  # Restore terminal echo
  stty echo
}

# If running from a terminal
if [ -t 1 ]
then
  # Program exit trap to cleanup and restore terminal echo on
  trap 'exit_trap' EXIT
  # Disable terminal echo
  stty -echo
fi

echo "going to sleep 5"
sleep 5
echo "finished sleeping"
```